# How to count words in a text file in c using functions

Tags: c++, c

I have been looking around for example of how to read a file and count how many words in a sentence, my understanding is counting how many white characters. Is that the approach I should take. I do have other questions but I want to get them done one by one. If I can avoid using the main function, I want to make a function of my own that is similar to the ones i'm using already but for words.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cctype>
#include<cstring>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

//single structure that contains all functions + the line itself
struct Counts
{
  int countChars;
  int countNW;
  int countAlpha;
  int countDigits;
  int countPunctuation;
};

//function names
int countChars(Counts&, char[]);
int countNW(Counts&, char[]);
int countAlpha(Counts&, char[]);
int countDigits(Counts&, char[]);
int countPunctuation(Counts&, char[]);
void printRprt(Counts&);  

int main()
{
  //open input file (C-style)
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("inp1.txt", "r");
  //error message
  if(fp == NULL)
  {
    printf("Could not open input file\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  //declare variables
  Counts counts;
  int i;
  char line[80];
  char delims[] = " ,\t\n"; //delimeters: space, ',', tab, return

  //get lines (max 80) from file
  //a line is a group of characters terminated by a \n
  //Call to the functions
  while(fgets(line, 80, fp))
  {
    printf(line);
    countChars(counts, line);
    countNW(counts, line);
    countAlpha(counts, line);
    countDigits(counts, line);
    countPunctuation(counts, line);
    printRprt(counts);
  }
}

/*
 * Function name: countChars
 * Output: An integer
 * Description: Counts how many characters are on the given line.
*/
int countChars(Counts& counts, char line[])
{
  counts.countChars=0;
  int i=0; 
  while (line[i] !='\0')
  {
   {
   counts.countChars++;
   }
  i++;
  }
}
/*
 * Function name: countNW
 * Output: An integer
 * Description: counts how many characters are not white space.
*/
int countNW(Counts& counts, char line[])
{
  counts.countNW=0;
  char c;
  int i=0;
  while (line[i]!='\0')
  {
    c= line[i];
    if (!isspace(c))
    {
    counts.countNW++;
    }
  i++;
  }
}

/*
 * Function name: countAlpha
 * Output: An integer
 * Description: counts how many characters are alphabetic letters.
*/
int countAlpha(Counts& counts, char line[])
{
  counts.countAlpha=0;
  int i=0;
  while (line[i]!='\0')
  {
    if (isalpha(line[i]))
    {
    counts.countAlpha++;
    }
    i++;
  }
}

/*
 * Function name: countDigits
 * Output: An integer
 * Description: Counts how many characters are numeric digits.
*/
int countDigits(Counts& counts, char line[])
{
  counts.countDigits=0;
  int i;
  i=0;
  while ((line[i]!='\0'))
  {
   if (isdigit(line[i]))
   {
   counts.countDigits++;
   }
  i++;
  }
}

/*
 * Function name: countPunctuation
 * Output: An integer
 * Description: Counts how many characters are punctuation. (non-numeric, non-alphabetical)
*/
int countPunctuation(Counts& counts, char line[])
{
  counts.countPunctuation=0;
  int i=0;
  int cx=0;
  while (line[i]!='\0')
  {
    if (ispunct(line[i]))
    {
    counts.countPunctuation++;
    }
   cx++;
   i++;
  }
}

/*
 * Function name: printReport
 * Output: Results of all the functions.
 * Description: Prints a report of all the functions.
*/
void printRprt(Counts& counts)
{
  cout <<"Total characters: " << counts.countChars <<"\nNon-white space: " << counts.countNW << "\nAlphabetic: " << counts.countAlpha <<"\nDigits: " << counts.countDigits << "\nPunctuation: " << counts.countPunctuation <<endl;
}
```

From my understanding, it look like I could sorta use the nonwhite spaces function but I wonder what could I edit so it could read words and not just each characters. If you can't understand, let me know before you down vote, please. Thanks!

Comment: this is marked as `c`, but you're using `cout`, which is `C++`.

Comment: That is true, I guess I could of either added that and/or changed it to printf.

Comment: Assuming words are separated by a white-space, the number of words would be the number of non-consecutive whitespace characters plus 1. You would need to ignore spaces before and after a sentence. Also, you would need to think whether hyphenated words, such as "top-down", are considered as a single word or 2 words.

Comment: I got what you mean. That really cleared up what I should do, Thank you pgngp. :P

Comment: You can do it in a few lines of code by simply calling `strtok` and tokenizing each line and counting the tokens, or by using an alternating combination of `strspn` or `strpbrk` to find whitespace and non-whitespace occurrences in a line.

Comment: I'd say it's not a lot more complicated than... `while(str<end) { while((str<end) && !isalpha(*str++)); ++words; while((str<end) && isalpha(*str++);}`. Well, slightly... must subtract 1 id it ends with a non-word char... will leave that as homework.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry no explanation when I first posted, I was called away.

If using C++, I would use regular expression classes from the standard library.  The code below is a quick hack that counts the items of interest for a file and also breaks it down per sentence in the file, where a sentence is something that ends with one or more of the punctuation marks '.', '!' or '?' and some white space.

The advantage of doing it this way is that it's fairly flexible and very little code to maintain.

The code could be improved.  main() should check for command-line arguments instead of blindly assuming there is one.  And should error if it can't open an if stream.  And should probably have a usage statement.  And the per-sentence code could be improved, for example using regex_replace() to remove newlines in the sentence before calling Countem().  These are easy additions.

The effort to learn how to use the regular expression facilities in the standard library will pay off fairly quickly for text processing activities.  They are very powerful.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

size_t Countem(const string & s, const string & re)
{
  regex  rgx(re);
  auto   b = sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), rgx);
  auto   e = sregex_iterator();
  return distance(b, e);
}

void PerSentence(const string & s)
{
  regex  sentence("[^\\!\\.\\?]+[\\!\\.\\?]+[ \t\n]+");
  auto   b = sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), sentence);
  auto   e = sregex_iterator();
  for ( ; b != e; ++b) {
    cout << "Sentence: " << b->str() << '\n'
         << "    Words: " << Countem(b->str(), "[^ \t\n]+") << '\n'
         << "    Alphas: " << Countem(b->str(), "[[:alpha:]]") << '\n'
         << "    Digits: " << Countem(b->str(), "[[:digit:]]") << '\n'
         << "    Punctuation: " << Countem(b->str(), "[[:punct:]]") << '\n';
  }
  return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  ifstream  is(argv[1]);
  string    s((istreambuf_iterator<char>(is)),
              istreambuf_iterator<char>());
  cout << "File:\n"
       << "    Words: " << Countem(s, "[^ \t\n]+") << '\n'
       << "    Alphas: " << Countem(s, "[[:alpha:]]") << '\n'
       << "    Digits: " << Countem(s, "[[:digit:]]") << '\n'
       << "    Punctuation: " << Countem(s, "[[:punct:]]") << '\n'
       << "    Sentences: " << Countem(s, "[\\!\\.\\?][ \t\n]+") << "\n\n";

  PerSentence(s);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to _StackOverflow_, you might want to read [how to post an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before doing so. Give a bit of context explaining why you posted that code and what does it do. Also consider taking the time to format your answer to be easily understood by readers.